# CreateMutex fails after impersonation

Tags: c++, windows, mutex, impersonation

Here's the code where I'me trying to impersonate a user and then create a mutex. The mutex is not getting created. I get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED error.

```
void Impersonate()
{
    DWORD logonType = LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE;
    DWORD logonProvider = LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT;
    HANDLE userToken;
    HANDLE hMutex;
    DWORD err;

    LPSTR user = "zoom"; // the user I created myself on my machine. 
    // It has Administrator privileges, and my account, 
    // from which I start the app, is Admin too
    LPSTR password = "zoom";
    LPSTR domain = ".";
    hMutex = NULL;

    LogonUserA(user, domain, password, logonType, logonProvider,&userToken);

    // just to make sure that mutexes are created fine before impersonation
    hMutex = CreateMutexA( NULL, FALSE, "mutex_good" );  

    ImpersonateLoggedOnUser(userToken);

    hMutex = CreateMutexA( NULL, FALSE, "mutex_797" ); // I can set any 
                                                       // random name, no difference
    if( hMutex == NULL )
    {
        err = GetLastError();
        // here err is ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED 
    }

    CloseHandle(userToken);
}
```

I've found several similar topics, but all of them were discussing creating same-name mutex from two different user contexts, i.e. a mutex "MUTEX_1" was already created before impersonation, and attempting to call CreateMutex with the same name but from an impersonated user was failing due to lack of privileges.

This is not the case here, as I am pretty sure that there is no mutex with the same name (or any mutex at all) being created before this code.

I guess I should pass something non-null into CreateMutex, but what exactly?

I'm not very good in Windows security.  I understand passing NULL as a first parameter of CreateMutex means that 'default' security attributes will be used.  In this case it will be security parameters associated to the thread, i.e. with impersonated user.

Am I correct with my assumptions?

Comment: RbMm's answer explains the technical reasons why this doesn't work, and also provides a workaround (albeit an unsupported one).  Since both accounts are admin, and assuming you are running the program with elevated privilege, a better workaround would be to specify `LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH` (instead of interactive) so the impersonation token has admin privilege.

Comment: BUT, better still would be to take a step back and ask why you are trying to create a mutex while impersonating in the first place.  That's a rather odd thing to do; what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @HarryJohnston - "albeit an unsupported one" - really we not need use `Restricted` subfolder. we can simply use `CreateMutexA(0, 0, "Global\\mutex_797");` with "Global\\" prefix only which is documented - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382954(v=vs.85).aspx . i confuse `\BaseNamedObjects` with `\GLOBAL??` initially and forget that really `Everyone` **have write access** to `\BaseNamedObjects`. sorry

Comment: @RbMm: huh.  I thought you needed admin privilege to create any object in the global namespace; I wasn't aware that only applied to file-mapping objects.  Thanks!  I agree that creating a global mutex is at least as good a workaround as using admin privilege, but I'm still doubtful that it makes sense for the OP to create a mutex while impersonating.  See also https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110928-00/?p=9533

Comment: @HarryJohnston - really `Everyone` can create objects in `\BaseNamedObjects`  ( `Global` ), even LowIntegrity process can do this. this is unlike `\GLOBAL??` which is privileged place. so global namespace is not "privileged" space and almost any can create objects here (except `Anonymous`). think this fact not well known

Comment: @HarryJohnston, well, I don't know exactly why our customer needs impersonation, but they call  ImpersonateLoggedOnUser and then use our toolkit, which creates mutexes inside. The provided code is just a reduced snippet to illustrate the problem, but actually there are som layers between. Since I can't control the impersonation parameters, I prefer to change the mutex creation code to create it in \\Global than make changes to documentation and explain our customers why they should use batch logon instead of interactive. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Ah.  Sounds like an unreasonable customer request to me, but of course it is your prerogative to cater to it anyway. :-)  RbMm's suggestion of creating global mutexes is definitely your best bet, but make sure you've thought about the consequences if more than one person is logged in and running your code.  You might also want to check out the blog post I mentioned above, I believe it mentions a number of other potential issues with impersonation you might want to watch out for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first of all you need understand [NT Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#nt_namespaces) and use [WinObj](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/winobj.aspx) tool.

this is like small file system in memory with folders and different "files" in it (here under "files" mean different object types - `Event`, `Mutant`(mutex), `Section`, `Device`, ...). every time when you create named object - it placed to some folder in [NT Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#nt_namespaces). folders here (like folders in NTFS) have security descriptors. as result not everybody can create object under any folder.

to paraphrase what you do on the file system language (maybe it will be more clear):

i (`John`) try create file "mutex_good" under `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` and this is ok. because this is my personal folder and I have write access to it.

then i login(impersonate) as `zoom` and try create file "mutex_797" again under `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` (`%USERPROFILE%` in both case expand to same path, say `c:\Users\John` impersonation not affect this)

and `zoom` fail to create file. why ? simply he have no rights to do this. only `John`, `Administartors`, `SYSTEM` have write access to `c:\Users\John` but not `zoom`.

now let return to [NT Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#nt_namespaces). when we call `CreateMutexA( NULL, FALSE, "mutex_797" );` where  is `"mutex_797"` will be placed ?

if you not `appcontainer` and not run in system `session 0` - you run in some user `session <N>` and your named objects will be placed in `\Sessions\<N>\BaseNamedObjects` directory, where N=1,2..

so call `CreateMutexA( NULL, FALSE, "mutex_797" );`

try create mutex at `\Sessions\<N>\BaseNamedObjects\mutex_797`

however in `\Sessions\<N>\BaseNamedObjects` exist next SymbolicLinks (this is like in NTFS file system):

```
Global -> \BaseNamedObjects
Local  -> \Sessions\<N>\BaseNamedObjects
Session -> \Sessions\BNOLINKS
```

so say if you call `CreateMutexA( NULL, FALSE, "Global\\mutex_797" );`

Object Manager try place your mutex under `\BaseNamedObjects\mutex_797`

for more info about this read [Kernel object namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382954(v=vs.85).aspx)

and of course we must understand [How AccessCheck Works](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446683(v=vs.85).aspx)

for directory objects defined the next access rights:

```
//
// Object Manager Directory Specific Access Rights.
//

#define DIRECTORY_QUERY                 (0x0001)
#define DIRECTORY_TRAVERSE              (0x0002)
#define DIRECTORY_CREATE_OBJECT         (0x0004)
#define DIRECTORY_CREATE_SUBDIRECTORY   (0x0008)
```

also can more read about this at [DirectoryObject DesiredAccess Flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566492(v=vs.85).aspx)

we need `DIRECTORY_CREATE_OBJECT` access (*Name-creation access to the directory object*) for create mutex (or event or any object) in Directory

now for understand why you can create mutex in `\Sessions\<N>\BaseNamedObjects` but `zoom` can not - need look for `Security Descriptor` for this folder. i dump it:

```
T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 000F000F S-1-5-90-0-1 DWM-1
0 00 000F000F S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 0B 10000000 S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
0 0B 10000000 S-1-3-0 CREATOR OWNER
0 00 000F000F S-1-5-21-4026734978-3280735129-2412320105-1001 John
0 0B 10000000 S-1-5-5-0-294807 LogonSessionId_0_294807
0 00 0002000F S-1-5-5-0-294807 LogonSessionId_0_294807
0 00 0002000F S-1-5-32-544 Administrators
0 02 00000003 S-1-1-0 Everyone
0 00 00000002 S-1-5-12 RESTRICTED
17 00 00000001 S-1-16-4096 Low Mandatory Level
```

so who have `DIRECTORY_CREATE_OBJECT` (4) here ? `DWM-1`, `SYSTEM`, `Administrators`, current logon session users (`LogonSessionId_0_294807` ), current user (`John`) - and all. `zoom` not have this access.

for example `Everyone` have (3) - `DIRECTORY_QUERY|DIRECTORY_TRAVERSE` - `Name lookup` and `Query` but not `Name creation`

you can ask where in this case I can create mutex after impersonation ? need use `\BaseNamedObjects` ( **global namespace** )OR `\BaseNamedObjects\Restricted` directory - I test it security descriptor and result :

for `\BaseNamedObjects`

```
T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 0002000F S-1-1-0 Everyone
0 00 00000002 S-1-5-12 RESTRICTED
0 00 000F000F S-1-5-90-0-0 
0 00 000F000F S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
17 00 00000001 S-1-16-4096 Low Mandatory Level
```

for `\BaseNamedObjects\Restricted`

```
T FL AcessMsK Sid
0 00 0002000F S-1-1-0 Everyone
0 00 0002000F S-1-5-12 RESTRICTED
0 00 000F000F S-1-5-90-0-0 
0 00 000F000F S-1-5-18 SYSTEM
17 00 00000001 S-1-16-4096 Low Mandatory Level
```

so how you can view `Everyone` here have 2000F - all needed access. hope `zoom` is member of `Everyone` ? next code I sure will be worked

`CreateMutexA(0, 0, "Global\\mutex_797");`

for `\BaseNamedObjects` (*global namespace*) exist one exception:

> The creation of a file-mapping object in the global namespace, by
>   using CreateFileMapping, from a session other than session zero is a
>   privileged operation. Because of this, an application running in an
>   arbitrary Remote Desktop Session Host (RD Session Host) server session
>   must have SeCreateGlobalPrivilege enabled in order to create a
>   file-mapping object in the global namespace successfully. The
>   privilege check is limited to the creation of file-mapping objects,
>   and does not apply to opening existing ones. For example, if a service
>   or the system creates a file-mapping object, any process running in
>   any session can access that file-mapping object provided that the user
>   has the necessary access.

but for Mutex or say Event - not need *SeCreateGlobalPrivilege* enabled

---

you also can say, but `zoom` is Administrator account and `Administrator` have access to `\Sessions\<N>\BaseNamedObjects` - so why this not work ? because with `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` and `UAC` system assign  to `zoom` filtered token. `Administrator` Group (`S-1-5-32-544`) exist in token **but** with [`SE_GROUP_USE_FOR_DENY_ONLY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379596(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute only - as result it ignores access-allowed ACEs for the SID. 
and `zoom` have another `LogonSessionId_0_XXX` SID - as result and `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`

as noted @Harry Johnston - if we will use `LOGON32_LOGON_BATCH` instead `LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE` - we got elevated token - here `Administrator` Group will be with [`SE_GROUP_ENABLED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379596(v=vs.85).aspx) attribute - is enabled for access checks for access-allowed  ACEs

or how i offered - use `Global\` prefix before name - for place object to `\BaseNamedObjects` where `Everyone` have full access

> I understand passing NULL as a first parameter of `CreateMutex` means
>   that 'default' security attributes will be used. In this case it will
>   be security parameters associated to the thread, i.e. with
>   impersonated user.

the first parameter - pointer to `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` let you overwrite default security descriptor  for the new object. this is control who will be have access to it. but this not give you more or less access to Directory where you try place object - you must have `DIRECTORY_CREATE_OBJECT` access granted and we can not affect this by `SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES` - this affect on *new object* but not on existing  Directory

and finally some visualization of [NT Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#nt_namespaces)
[image]

Comment: @engf-010 - sorry English not my native language and I not good in it. I try describe that simply not all tokens have access to default object directory - as result `zoom` is fail create mutex here. but he can create it at `"Global\Restricted\mutex_797` - here less strict SD

Comment: :MUCH better. As a non-native english reader ,this I can understand.

Comment: That's fine, I'm not native speaker too, and your answer is clear and very helpful.

Comment: So, my misake was in assumption that named object ar created in independent namspace, and each user has his own namespace, something like \Users\John\BaseNamedObjects\mutex_good and \Users\zoom\BaseNamedObjects\mutex_797. Now I see this is not the case, and objects are created under "session" namespace, and I can not change the session by impersonation (or in any other way, since a whole process belongs to some session, and this session is owned by user who started the process)

Comment: @VladimirNavrotsky - yes, named objects localized by Sessions `ID`. for system `session 0` - `\BaseNamedObjects` folder used.
for `session N` (where N > 0) - `\Sessions\N\BaseNamedObjects` used. however by using `Global` SymbolicLink you can "redirect" place to `\BaseNamedObjects` - `CreateMutexA(0, 0, "Global\\mutex_797");` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa382954(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @VladimirNavrotsky - I make update - add more info - really we can use and  `CreateMutexA(0, 0, "Global\\mutex_797"); ` - without `Restricted` subfolder. I confuse this with `\GLOBAL??` initially